All the XOR gates are not working and there is no error present

When i put any XOR circuit in the schematic capture then run the simulation i receive a (no model specified) error, i searched online and the solution i found to this error was just toggling the (Attach hierarchy module) option on,    but after i do that and run the simulation the XOR circuits doesn't generate an output no matter what input it recives and the output box color is gray no blue (logical 0) or red (logical 1). 

what is your specific question? ... please add a focused, answerable question to your post

not working does not describe what actually happens  ... please update your post with a description of what XOR gates do
